# Maintain a Dictionary with WCF RESTful Service

Tags: c#, wcf, dictionary, restful-architecture

I need to write a RESTful WCF service that maintains a dictionary (or any other suitable data structure) with userId:userData as key:value pairs.
For that I first need to implement an interface for getting and setting userData (the specific configuration is enclosed):

GetConfiguration() : returns default config when user hasn’t set a config yet

GetConfiguration(string id)

SetConfiguration(string id, Configuration configurationSchema)

Then I'll need to write a service that implements this interface.

As a newbie in WCF I'm not sure how to do it. I tried to look for relevant references but didn't found any.

Appreciate any help/relevant references, Thanks !

The userData object:

```
public class ConfigurationSchema
{
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public List<string> Habits { get; set; }
    public ConfigurationSchema(string mobileNumber, List<string> habits)
    {
        this.MobileNumber = mobileNumber;
        this.Habits = habits;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be below video will help you to create a WCF service. Once create simple WCF service after that add your code.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GzN1vHWlJjA

Answer (score 0):

If you did not find references to help you, I'd suggest you learn to google before you tackle programming problems. It's worth it. For your problem:

- Open Visual Studio
- Chose WCF project
- Replace example complex data structure by your own class
- Rename methods
- Rename interface
- Press F5